# Data migration from non-magento DB about sales_order tables

Tags: magento2, sales-order, migration

I have working on data migration from non-magento e-com website to  magento 2.x EE. I have question about that I can't save the data after call `save()`;

```
$customerOrder = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order');
$customerOrder->setData('base_grand_total',$val->_amount); 

//total = shipping fee + items total
$customerOrder->setData('base_subtotal',$val->_orginal_price); //item totals
$customerOrder->setData('base_shipping_amount',$val->_shipping_fee);
$customerOrder->setData('base_to_global_rate',1);
$customerOrder->setData('base_to_order_rate',1);
$customerOrder->setData('store_id',1);//store ID
$customerOrder->setData('grand_total',$val->_amount);
$customerOrder->setData('subtotal',$val->_orginal_price);
$customerOrder->setData('total_qty_ordered',1);

$Orderpayment->save();
```

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on null in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\hktshop_uat\vendor\magento\module-payment\Observer\SalesOrderBeforeSaveObserver.php
>   on line 24

Anyone have experience on migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to set payment method for our order, for example:

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
    //$orderPayment = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderPaymentInterface');
    $orderPayment = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment');

    $orderPayment->setStoreId($this->_store_id)
        ->setMethod('checkmo')
        ->setPoNumber(' - ');
    $order->setPayment($orderPayment);
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, I can save the data into sales_order & sales_order_payment table by your suggestion. But I can't open the order detail on admin page.   


which tables or data I miss to insert ?
The error : 
> Order View
Information Changes have been made to this section that have not been saved. This tab contains invalid data. Please resolve this before saving.